# CiviVolunteer Fatal error clicking on Volunteer Now - Resolved

Tags: civievent, civivolunteer

I received the follow fatal error when trying to volunteer for an event.  The roles have been configured.  I did not select the public option.  It was resolved by ticking public.

```
#**backTrace**

#0 `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(360): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()`
#1 `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/default/custom_ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/Form/VolunteerSignUp.php(117): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Project has no public volunteer needs enabled")`
#2 `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(455): CRM_Volunteer_Form_VolunteerSignUp->preProcess()`
#3 `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(94): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()`
#4 `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Volunteer_Form_VolunteerSignUp), "display")`
#5 `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Volunteer_Form_VolunteerSignUp), "display")`
#6 `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")`
#7 `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(115): CRM_Core_Controller->run()`
#8 `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(286): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Volunteer_Form_VolunteerSignUp", "Volunteer Signup", NULL)`
#9 `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))`
#10 `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))`
#11 `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(489): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))`
#12 `[internal function](): civicrm_invoke("volunteer", "signup")`
#13 `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))`
#14 `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/RCSQ/drupal/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()`
#15 `{main}`
```

Comment: This one has caught me out as well - noted! What would be neat is a post-install instructions screen for extensions :) Even just a redirect to a URL (either internal or external) after installation would be neat.